# Google SDK iOS asks for offline access

Tags: ios, google-signin

I have integrated "Google Sign-In for iOS" in my app but, at every login, Google asks the user for Offline Access.

I have read some answers about it (to disable `approval_prompt` or to set `access_type` to `online`) but it is not avaliable in Google SDK.

Do you know about it ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey do you find something ? I have opposite problem I can't get  offline access can you put some code please :)

Comment: sorry, I haven't found anything...

Comment: Can you put some code ? Maybe we could help each other

Comment: i will try to find this old code..